# Is there an R function to extract images based on a unique date and time stamp?

Tags: r, macos, filter, photo, extract

I have a set of photos from camera traps with multiple images of identical date and time stamps. I need to extract one photo for each timestamp in the set. I need every photo where there is only one photo with that date and time stamp. Then for any multiple date and time stamps I must always take only the second photo. Eg. One photo, X, timestamp 13:22:42, I want photo X; three photos, a, b and c, have timestamp 13:22:43, I want b. Seven photos, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 have timestamp 13:22:44, I want 2.

I am completely new to R, but thought it sounded like the kind of thing it might be able to do! I have tried googling options, but not much luck.

I am hoping I can either rename all the photos I want to easily copy and paste them in to a new album, or ideally have R extract them into a new folder for me. Is this possible?

Comment: How can R extract the timestamp from the photos? Is it in the name of the file?

Comment: If the timestamp is in the name of the image, please provide a sample of that name format. If you're trying to pull the system time stamp (i.e. when the file was created), that is important information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use the system "Created At" timestamp, this is one way to do it. First, we get a list of the file names. Then we use `file.info` to get the "Created At" time. We then group by timestamp, and create a grouping id with `row_number`. We then filter to the second image `id == 2` where `max(id) >= 2`, otherwise if there's only one image we use `id == 1`. Then we can create a new folder and copy the selected images there.

```
library(tidyverse)    

setwd(choose.dir())

# select the folder with your images in it

files <- list.files()

keep <- files %>% file.info() %>% 
  select(ctime) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("file") %>%
  group_by(ctime) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(id == min(max(id),2)) %>% 
  pull(file)

# at this point `keep` is a list of file names meeting the specified criteria

dir.create("Keep")

file.copy(keep, paste0("./Keep/", keep))
```